# Does anyone know about issues between Citrix and Delphi 2007 applications? (And perhaps other development languages?)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, citrix

The situation is simple. I've created a complex Delphi application which uses several different techniques. The main application is a WIN32 module but a few parts are developed as .NET assemblies. It also communicates with a web service or retrieves data from a specific website. It keeps most of it's user-data inside an MS Access database with some additional settings inside the Registry. In-memory, all data is converted inside an XML document, which is occasionally saved to disk as backup in case the system crashes. (Thus allowing the user to recover his data.) There's also some data in XML files for read-only purposes. The application also executes other applications and wants for those to finish. All in al, it's a pretty complex application.

We don't support Citrix with this application, although a few users do use this application on a Citrix server. (Basically, it allows those users to be more mobile.) But even though we keep telling them that we don't support Citrix, those customers are trying to push us to help them with some occasional problems that they tend to have.

The main problem seems to be an occasional random exception that seems to pop up on Citrix systems. Never at the same location and often it looks related to some memory problems. We've p[lenty of error reports already and there are just too many different errors. So I know solving all those will be complex.

So I would like to go a bit more generic and just want to know about the possible issues a Delphi (2007) can have when it's run on a Citrix system. Especially when this application is not designed to be Citrix-aware in any way. We don't want to support Citrix officially but it would be nice if we can help those customers. Not that they're going to pay us more, but still...

So does anyone know some common issues a Delphi application can have on a Citrix system?
Does anyone know about common issues with Citrix in general?
Is there some Silver Bullet or Golden Hammer solution somewhere for Citrix problems?

Btw. My knowledge about Citrix is limited to [this Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrix_Systems) entry and [this website](http://www.citrix.com/)... And a bit I've [Googled](http://www.google.com/search?q=Citrix)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were some issues in the past with Published Delphi Applications on Citrix having no icon in the taskbar. I think this was resolved by the MainFormOnTaskbar (available in D2007 and higher). Apart from that there's not much difference between Terminal Server and Citrix (from the Application's perspective), the most important things you need to account for are:

- Users are NEVER administrator on a Terminal or Citrix Server, so they no rights in the Local Machine part of the registry, the C drive, Program Folder and so on.
- It must be possible for multiple users on the same system to start your application concurrently.
- Certain folders such as the Windows folder are redirected to prevent possible application issues, this is also means that API's like GetWindowsFolder do not return the real windows folder but the redirected one. Note that this behaviour can be disabled by setting a particular flag in the PE header (see [delphi-and-terminal-server-aware](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/11/24/delphi-and-terminal-server-aware/)).
- Sometimes multiple servers are used in a farm which means your application can run on any of these servers, the user is redirected to the least busy server at login (load balancing). Thefore do not use any local database to store things.
- If you use an external database or middleware or application server note that multiple users will connect with the same computername and ip address (certain Citrix versions can use Virtual IP addresses to address this).

Answer (score 3):

Many of our customers use our Delphi applications on Citrix. Generally speaking, it works fine. We had printing problems with older versions of Delphi, but this was fixed in a more recent version of Delphi (certainly more recent than Delphi 2007). However, because you are now running under terminal services, there are certain things which will not work, with or without Citrix. For example, you cannot make a local connection to older versions of InterBase, which use a named pipe without the GLOBAL modifier. Using DoubleBuffered would also be a really bad idea. And so on. My suggestion is to look for advice concerning Win32 apps and Terminal Services, rather than looking for advice on Delphi and Citrix in particular. The one issue which is particular to Citrix that I'm aware of is that you can't count on having a C drive available. Hopefully you haven't hard-coded any drive letters into your code, but if you have you can get in trouble.

Comment: Nope, no hardcoded paths in our own code, although a few third-party modules did have some minor problems because they wanted to be installed in the program files folder which had to be located on the C: drive. Then again, we don't support terminal services and we've just referred those customers to the other party. (Those modules are stand-alone applications and our software can communicate with those others.)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, your application needs to be compatible with MS Terminal Services in order to work with XenApp.  My understanding is that .NET applications are Terminal Services-compatible, and so by extension should also work in a Citrix environment.  Obviously, as you're suffering some problems, it's not quite that simple, however.

There's a testing and verification kit available from http://community.citrix.com/citrixready that you may find helpful.  I would imagine the Test Kit and Virtual Lab tools will be of most use to you.  The kit is free to use, but requires sign-up.

Comment: Most of the application is based on WIN32, not .NET. And we've not added any support for any terminal services. Most users just use our software on a desktop or laptop.

Comment: Ah, sorry missed that bit about Win32 in the question.  Even so, the Citrix Ready toolkit should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Security can be an issue.  If sensitive folders are not "sandboxed" (See Remko's discussion about redirection), the user can break out of your app and run things that they shouldn't.  You should probe your app to see what happens when they "shell out" of your app. Common attack points are CHM Help, any content that uses IE to display HTML, and File Open/Save dialogs.
ex: If you show .chm help, the user can right-click within a help topic, View Source. That typically opens Notepad. From there, they can navigate the directory structure.  If they are not properly contained, they may be able to do some mischief.
ex: If they normally don't have a way to run Internet Explorer, and your app has a clickable URL in the about box or a "visit our web site" in the Help menu, voila! they have access to the web browser.  If unrestrained, they can open a command shell by navigating to the windows directory.