# How can I make my form resize more smoothly?

Tags: delphi, forms, resize, flicker, smoothing

When resizing a form with many controls, the form looks bad because of flickering. What are some tips to have a smoother form resizing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.WMEnterSizeMove(var Message:TWMMove);
begin
  Self.DisableAlign;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMExitSizeMove(var Message:TWMMove);
begin
  Self.EnableAlign;
end;
```

Comment: That's fine at preventing flicker, but it also seems to prevent alignment altogether. I added an Invalidate call after enabling alignment: not perfect, because you cannot see exactly what effect the form resize is going to have, but at least it eliminates all flicker on a complex multi-panel form.

Comment: procedure WMEnterSizeMove(var Message:TWMMove); message WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE;

    procedure WMExitSizeMove(var Message:TWMMove); message WM_EXITSIZEMOVE;

does not fire the aproporiate events. Actually forgot to mention it is a frame and not a form but I guessed that it would have been the same.

Answer (score 5):

Try using WM_SETREDRAW ([**not** LockWindowUpdate](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/22/1742084.aspx)).

You might also have a look at [DeferWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632681(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: +1, both very good pieces of advise in itself. These probably won't help with a complex VCL form using alignment, nested controls and so on, though. `DeferWindowPos()` is worth testing for manual placement in `OnResize` handler.

Answer (score 5):

Complex forms are often made up of nested panels, and the repaint process may cause flickering. If this is the case with your project there are two easy solutions that *might* help:

1. Disable the property **`FullRepaint`** on your panels.
2. Enable the property **`DoubleBuffered`** on your form. You won't find this property on the object inspector, so put **`DoubleBuffered := true;`** in FormCreate.

Comment: Note that `DoubleBuffered` trades less flicker for slower update speed, an effect that can be noticeable on large screens, where resizing may become "jumpy" with larger window sizes.

Comment: DoubleBuffered basically makes your app useless on Citrix and Terminal Server.

Comment: >>> "DoubleBuffered basically makes your app useless on Citrix and Terminal Server"
Can you specify why?

Comment: @Alexander: See the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408664/why-is-doublebuffered-disabled-by-default

Comment: DoubleBuffered: see http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_1537.asp?SK= and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444830/does-anyone-know-about-issues-between-citrix-and-delphi-2007-applications-and-p

Comment: @JeroenPluimers +1 for "paying your taxes" and detecting when you're in a terminal services session (e.g. Remote Desktop Connection)

Answer (score 1):

I've got around this as follows:

1. In the 'OnResize' event of the form, have a routine to hide all child controls and then start a timer with a tick of about 500ms.
2. When the timer fires, disable it and then set all child controls to visible.

By playing around with this activity you get a form that goes blank whilst you are sizing it, but then populates itself neatly when you 'let go'.

Bri

Comment: I think you would find that handling the enter/exit size move messages (with the modification noted in my comment above) produces a better user experience because you can at least see the (unsized) form while you resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid flicker by aligning no more than **1** non-`alClient` component per parent, always paired with a `alClient` (e.g. a `TPanel`) to contain all other components. Group them in panels without borders.

Say you want to allign three things: `alLeft`, `alTop` and `alClient` for the main view.
Dont do this:

`Form
  alTop
  alLeft
  alClient   // your main view`

But instead embed these as follows:

`Form
  alTop
  alClient    // panel to avoid flicker
    alLeft
    alClient  // your main view`

Same story for embedding several `alTop` elements.